# how to pass a value to model function in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to pass a user id value in variable $userID, to a function in a Model class Clientmodel.  The function is get_username(), now in a model do I have to define that function to accept a variable as a parameter?  so.. get_username($userID)? Just want to know how is the recommended way in code igniter?

Thanks!

tariq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really depends on what you use the model for. Most of the time, it will make sense to have a parameter to the method and use that every time:

```
// Model
function get_username($userID)
{
    // do something with $userID
}

// Controller
$this->some_model->get_username($some_id);
```

On the other hand, sometimes it makes sense for the Model to be "stateful" -- do you have ***one*** userID per controller? Will it ever be more than one? Do you need the userID in a large number of methods of that model? Then maybe this will make sense instead:

```
// Model
function set_userid($userID)
{
    $this->userID = $userID;
}

function get_username()
{
    // do something with $this->userID
}

// Controller
$this->some_model->set_userid( $some_id );
$this->some_model->get_username();
```

Other times, you may have one userID which you plan on using over and over, but sometimes you need to use another value, that is when default arguments come into play:

```
// Model
function set_userid($userID)
{
    $this->userID = $userID;
}

function get_username( $userID = NULL )
{
    if( $userID === NULL ) $userID = $this->userID;
    // do something with $userID (not $this->userID)
}


// Controller
$this->some_model->set_userid( $some_id );
$this->some_model->get_username();
```

Comment: `function get_username( $userID = $this->userID )` is not correct, that will trigger errors. Otherwise good points, except you shouldn't make it mandatory to use `set_userid()` in that second code block, still allow the variable to be passed.

Comment: @Wesley RE: parameter default: d'oh. Goof up, plain, ol' fashioned mistake. Fixed now. RE: Second code block: Not necessarily, there are times when it is conceivable that you don't want to allow someone to modify the contents of the function directly ('sides that's what the final block is for), but I will leave it as "stylistic choice" and that for the vast majority of the time I will agree with you (actually, I *loathe* keeping states and avoid it as much as possible, so I would probably just add a parameter).

Comment: Yeah I agree, it depends. I realized my second note was debatable as soon as the 5 minute editing window expired :) I hope this all isn't going over OP's head...

Comment: @Wesley Murch Well, if it is, hopefully he'll comment on this and we can improve the answer even more.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is not Codeigniter specific in any way, it's just basic PHP. Your model is a [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), and `get_username()` is a [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) that takes [arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

The most basic way to do it is this:

```
// Model
function get_username($userID)
{
    // do something with $userID
}

// Controller
$this->some_model->get_username($some_id);
```

Make sure you read about [default arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) so you can decide what to do if `$userID` is not passed (you may not need a default here though), and make sure you check that the value is valid.